# How can I change the functionality of breadcrumbs?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

So I've tried with the Woocommerce breadcrumbs and a plugin called Breadcrumbs NAVXT. Both show the breadcrumbs when I go from a category to a product, the subcategory in the breadcrumbs. Even though whenever I click on a product, I want the breadcrumbs leading to that page. So when I go for example from:

```
miscellaneous -> product1
```

I don't want the breadcrumbs:

```
miscellaneous -> subcategory -> product1
```

Only if I actually went to the product through that subcategory. I looked at the documentation of the plugin:

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

And it has filters and actions, but not with a lot of explanation. I've also searched how to do this with the default Woocommerce breadcrumbs, but I can't find how to do that in Woocommerce either.

There must be a setting or set the way the breadcrumbs should work right? I've also tried to turn on and off some options in the plugin settings, but it didn't give me the desired output either.

Comment: With default WooCommerce breadcrumbs, you can easily manage when to show or hide the breadcrumbs. Refer to this documentation : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: @PatricePoliquin I'm sorry but how would I make it so when I go through `Miscellaneous -> product1` it shows that, and when I go through `miscellaneous -> subcategory -> product1` to show the subcategory as well? I can't find that in the link you provided.

Comment: @Loko have you found the solution?

Comment: @MantasLukosevicius I used a plugin to fix this

Comment: @Loko can you tell which one?

Comment: @MantasLukosevicius Sorry I'm not quite sure right now since it was a year ago, It's also that I do not have the code with me anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Yoast SEO Plugin? It offers breadcrumbs setup in its dashboard.

Just go to the plug setting and follow these settings

- Click on ‘Search Appearance’.
- Click on the ‘Breadcrumbs’ tab.
- Toggle the ‘Breadcrumbs’ switch and configure the settings according 
  to your requirements.

Do let me know if it doesn't work! 
Thanks

Comment: I am using Yoast SEO, but I cant find a setting to get the breadcrumbs as described in my question

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDllnDsnoEk
this youtube video might help